# bind multiple values in Ember Select

Tags: ember.js

Say I have some student

```
{"student":{"name": "Sarah", "schoolId": "29102", "studentId": "88473"}}
```

And both these numbers are necessary in identifying this student, and they're variable in length so I can't just parse them.

If I am using a drop down via ember select, is it possible to bind multiple values to a selection.

I know this doesn't work, but I hope this conveys what I would like to do.

```
    {{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding = 'students'
    optionLabelPath = "content.studentName"
    optionValuePath = "content.schoolId", "content.studentId"
    valueBinding = "selectedSchoolId", "selectedStudentId"
    selectionBinding = "selectedStudentName"
    }}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to go is to create a computed property in your models which is the concatenation of both ids. if both ids are unique, then their concatenation is also unique.

From my experience, having a unique identifier whenever possible always simplifies things.

By the way, I'm the creator of ember-selectize, but I believe your problem is more general and not solvable by just using a different kind of select box.

Comment: I wanted to see if there was another way beyond concatenation because i wanted to avoid having to parse the values. All is well though, I managed to figure out some stuff in the back end so I can bypass the need for multiple bindings. Thanks!

Comment: This would be merely a computed property, not a real property. It would not be sent to the server. Why would you need to parse information?
Anyway, the problem is solved. All is well. :)